# How to pad an image to match another image's size using padarray in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am trying to use `padarray` to increase the size of `image2`, which is `256 x 256` to the size of `image1`, which is of size `384 x 512`, but I get that the new `image3` is of size `1024 x 1280`. Why and what is wrong?

This is the code I wrote:

```
Image1 = rgb2gray(imread('pillsetc.png'));
Image2 = (imread('rice.png'));
[height1, width1] = size(Image1);
[height2, width2] = size(Image2);

image3 = padarray(Image2,[height1, width1]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is arising from the fact that you're misunderstanding how `padarray` works.  The second element specifies how many elements you want to pad along the border of the image for each dimension.  For example, doing `out = padarray(im, [2 1]);` will specify a border of 2 zeroes vertically and 1 zero horizontally.

Example:

```
>> im = [1 2; 3 4]

im =

     1     2
     3     4

>> padarray(im, [2 1])

ans =

     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     1     2     0
     0     3     4     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
```

Take note that the padding **is symmetric**.  So the `2` in the first dimension means that you see a 2 pixel zero border on top of the image and on the bottom.  The `1` in the second dimension means that you see a 1 pixel zero border to the left and right of the image.  You are specifying the total width and height instead, which isn't correct.  In addition, if you have a colour image, `width1` and `width2` would actually become `width*3` where `width` is the original width of either image.

If you want to do this correctly, you'll need to calculate the correct padding size for the width and height of the image, and you'll also need to get the correct width and height from the two images:

```
Image1 = rgb2gray(imread('pillsetc.png'));
Image2 = (imread('rice.png'));
height1 = size(Image1,1); %// Change
width1 = size(Image1,2); %// Change
height2 = size(Image2,1); %// Change
width2 = size(Image2,2); %// Change

image3 = padarray(Image2,[(height1-height2)/2, (width1-width2)/2]); %// Change
```

`height1-height2` and `width1-width2` finds the difference in height and width, which is the total number of zeroes required in both dimensions.  However, because the padding is done **symmetrically**, what you have to do is divide each value by 2 so half of the difference has this many zeroes on one side and the rest gets placed on the other side for each dimension.  In effect, you are placing the smaller image in the centre, and are padding around the centre of the image.  Also, bear in mind that this only works for even sized dimensions between both images.  If you don't have this, you'll want to perhaps use `floor`.

Comment: I got this error:Error using padarray
Expected input number 2, PADSIZE, to be integer-valued.

Error in padarray>ParseInputs (line 84)
validateattributes(padSize, {'double'}, {'real' 'vector' 'nonnan' 'nonnegative' ...

Error in padarray (line 64)
[a, method, padSize, padVal, direction] = ParseInputs(varargin{:});

Error in Untitled (line 19)
image3 = padarray(Image2,[(height1-height2+1)/2, (width1-width2+1)/2]);

Comment: @user1218499 Please see the edit.  Basically, get rid of the `+1` for both dimensions.