# Matlab - padarray background

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

Is it possible that the background of the new image generated by the padarray will be white and not black?

```
clc;
clear;
Image = (imread('rice.png'));
h = size(Image,1);  
w = size(Image,2);  

imageNew = padarray(Image,[w*2, h*2]);
imshow(imageNew);
```

Comment: Hi, are you related to this user who asked this question?  The beginning of your code is suspiciously similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33682187/how-to-pad-an-image-to-match-another-images-size-using-padarray-in-matlab/33682367#33682367.  The brackets surrounding `imread` are the telltale sign, not to mention the image name is also the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  `padarray` has a third optional parameter where you can specify what values the padded values should take on, instead of them being zero:

```
imageNew = padarray(Image,[w*2, h*2], 255); %// Change from black to white
```

BTW, if you read the documentation, it would tell you this: http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/padarray.html.

As a word of advice, try reading the documentation before posting a question in the future.  I'm certainly not criticizing your skills for reading, but MATLAB's documentation is very comprehensive.  Your answer was found by reading the docs!